# How to Update Embedded map in orientdb?

Tags: orientdb

I have a embedded map entry in my DB class as follows.

Json string:

```
{
"dataStep2": "{stepno: 2,content:'', icon:'plug icon', color:'olive', header:'Uptime Guarantee',headcolor:'ffffff', tagline:'Check out our plug-in marketplace',taglinecolor:'ffffff', isActive:true}",
    "dataStep3": "{stepno: 3,content:'', icon:'plug icon', color:'blue', header:'Uptime Guarantee',headcolor:'ffffff', tagline:'Check out our plug-in marketplace',taglinecolor:'ffffff', isActive:true}"
}
```

I want to update only one part oe embedded map. For a example "datastep2" values.
Please Advice me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
update #24:0 set embed.dataStep2="{stepno: 2,content:'', icon:'plug icon', color:'green', header:'Uptime Guarantee',headcolor:'ffffff', tagline:'Check out our plug-in marketplace',taglinecolor:'ffffff', isActive:true}"
```

Where `#24:0` is a rid of the record that you want to update, and `embed` is the property containing `EMBEDDEDMAP` data with `dataStep2` and `dataStep3` from your example.

Comment: This method remove other records( this removes datastep3). i want to update only one while other values remaining same.